# How to fetch the Public IP of the newly launched machine using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform

I have created two instances (`Instance-1` and `Instance-2`) in **AWS** using **Terraform**. I installed Ansible on `Instance-1` in the same script and I want to push a playbook to `Instance-2` from `Instance-1`.

I want to specify the public-IP, username and key path to the **Ansible Host** file inside `Instance-1` where I installed Ansible.

How can I fetch the public-IP of `Instance-2` for specifying the aforementioned attributes in the Ansible host file ?

Answer (score 7):

If you're like me, with terraform and ansible runs as separate steps in a bigger orchestration, use terraform outputs to save off the IP address(es) you need during ansible. For example, we provision a whole cluster with terraform, only allowing SSH from a bastion host. I use the following to save off the bastion's IP address (it's behind an elastic IP):

```
output "bastion.ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.bastion.public_ip}"
}
```

Then to retrieve it after `terraform apply`:

```
bash-4.3# terraform output bastion.ip
52.1.2.3
```

Comment: AFAICT this doesn't work b/c output names can't have periods.  You need to say `output "bastion_ip" {...}` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the public_ip of the launched instances through terrraform using,

resource "aws_instance" "web" {

## ....

provisioner "local-exec" {

```
command = "echo ${aws_instance.web.public_ip} >> /path/to/save"
```

}

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html